# Push notifications in restlet

Tags: restlet

Can anyone please guide me from where I can get support or help for implementing asynchronous http requests (push notifications) using restlet (java restful api)

Comment: I have not tried this but might help: http://gulvaniharesh.blogspot.com/2013/08/push-notification-for-ios-and-android.html